# What does "be not for turning" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, british-english

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-47333307).

> "But what about the money?" I press on. "Going by your declaration, it's going to take 10 years for you to earn the registration fee - let alone to pay it back." Yuriy's **not for turning**. "It was borrowed," he says. "And anyway, it's worth the risk. I'm doing this to change the lives of every Ukrainian."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to Margaret Thatcher, who once said in a speech

> "You turn if you want to; the lady's **not for turning**."

*Not for* means not in favour of, as one might say "I'm for equality" to mean they support equality.

The intended clever part of the line was *you turn*, which was intended as a pun for [U-turn](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/u-turn), a type of manoeuvre in a car where you turn to point in the opposite direction in a smooth, uninterrupted movement. In UK politics, it means to abruptly change direction in terms of policy. I believe the equivalent term in American politics is "flip-flop". Margaret Thatcher had been urged to reverse a policy, to do a political u-turn, and her speechwriter came up with "you turn if you want to; the lady's not for turning."

In this case, it is a way of indicating that this Yuriy is unwilling to change his plans.

Comment: Thatcher's usage was itself riffing off [***The Lady's Not for Burning***,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady%27s_Not_for_Burning) a 1948 play by Christopher Fry.

Comment: I don't think we need follow every reference back to a putative original thought ;)

Comment: If it *hadn't* been for the antecedent, Thatcher's usage would have been universally met with a bemused ***Huh? What on earth is she on about?***

Comment: Not sure about that. Not sure most people were aware of the play. It's a sentence that makes sense and is grammatical.

Comment: I think you'll find that most UK newspapers who might have had reason to suspect their readers wouldn't be aware of the reference would have explicitly flagged it up when originally reporting the speech. It might "make sense", but it would have been a *very* strange thing to say, even in the context of the other "pun" *(**u-turn = you turn**)*. Apart from anything else, you'd at least expect ***this** lady*, not ***the** lady*, when she was referring to herself.

Comment: I was born in Thatcher's Britain, and while that was said all the time, no-one made reference to the play. Thatcher herself is reported to have missed the reference, and her being "the Lady" would easily be taken as a reference to her sobriquet of "the Iron Lady", a nickname she had long before that speech.

Comment: Next you'll be telling me her (Russian-bestowed) sobriquet *The Iron Lady* had nothing to do with [*The Iron Curtain.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Curtain)

Comment: I think it was more to do with The Iron Duke, myself, when she adopted it, but I expect both were relevant. But pretty much everyone knew that. Yes, the speechwriter was referring to the play. No, it wasn't terribly important to the audience.

Comment: And no one would be bemused by the turn of phrase.

Comment: [Why was Margaret Thatcher called "The Iron Lady" by Russian President Brezhnev?](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-Margaret-Thatcher-called-The-Iron-Lady-by-Russian-President-Brezhnev) - *It was a **Soviet journalist** who coined the moniker the Iron Lady for Margaret Thatcher. Intended as an insult, by the time she left office, for Russians it became a term of affection, or at the very least, grudging respect.* I don't think anyone seriously drew or draws any parallel with The Iron Duke.

Comment: I'm saying that when Thatcher adopted it, she wanted to draw that parallel. What PM wouldn't want to draw parallels with Wellington?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90167/discussion-between-sambc-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: @SamBC - only the other day, I saw a Cockney barrow-boy accidentally drop his cigar in a puddle. He turned to me and said 'That stogie's not for burning, as that playwright bloke Christopher Fry might've said '.